# File Copy over the network

Tags: file-copying

I have a large number of small size files. I want to copy them from one shared location to another shared location on windows. I am using Robocopy for this. However to copy paste one file it takes almost 13 seconds. Could you please let me know what other options we can use. We dont want to use any external tools.

Comment: If you have a really slow connection, zip up the files before copying: then it is only one copy instead of several.  You can use powershell to zip up the files: no need for external tools.

Answer (score 0):

It was an issue of location difference. I copied my batch file to actual machine of the shared location. Now its working really fast.